# Why is there a parsha break in the middle of a verse?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshat-devarim

In this week's parsha, we see a parsha (stumah) "break" in the middle of [Devarim 2:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0502.htm).

There are several other places where there is a parsha break in the middle of the verse. Another example occurs in [Bamidbar 26:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0426.htm). Aseret Hadibrot (10 commandments) also has this. I am not referring to Az Yashir or Ha'azinu as these are written in a special style, and are not considered "parshi'ot" according to the usual rules.

Is there a general reason why there is a parsha break in the middle of a verse, or does each verse have its own unique reason? If it's the 2nd reason, can you explain why there is a break in Devarim 2:8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons the Or HaChaim gives on that pasuk in parshas Pinchas for the piska in the middle of the passuk is those words 'and it was after the plague' serve one purpose for the preceding parsha and another purpose for the upcoming parsha.

This reasoning would apply to the passuk in Devarim as well. 'They turned to pass the way of the desert of Moav' is both the end of the narrative where they did not pass through the land of Eisav, it also serves as the introduction to the next parsha of not paining Moav, being that they are now actually close enough to do just that.

Comment: This is my contribution. There are other reasons in the Or HaChaim there if anyone else wants to darshan:)